# How to modify the default mapper of the StringConverter class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to read a csv file in Python3 using the numpy genfromtxt function. In my csv file I have a field which is a string that looks like the following: "0x30375107333f3333".

I need to use the "dtype=None" option because I need this section of code to work with many different csv files, only some of them having such a field. Unfortunately numpy interprets this as a float128 which is a pain because 1) it is not a float and 2) I cannot find  way to convert it to an int after it has been read as a float128 (without losing precision).

What I would like to do is instead interpret this as a string because it is enough for me. I found on the [Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#choosing-the-data-type) that there is a way of getting around this, but they give cryptic instructions:

> This behavior may be changed by modifying the default mapper of the StringConverter class.

Unfortunately whenever I Google something related to this I fall back to this documentation page.

I would greatly appreciate either an explanation of what they mean in the above quoted text or a solution to my above stated problem.

Comment: `dtype=object` then?

Comment: Hopefully your SO question will break the vicious cycle.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ unfortunately this means now all datatypes are interpreted as "object" including numbers previously interpreted as ints, floats, etc.